# Why is declaration-seq in the C++ standard written this way?

Tags: c++, parsing, c++11, c++14, language-lawyer

```
declaration-seq:
   declaration
   declaration-seq declaration
```

not this way:

```
declaration-seq:
   declaration
   declaration declaration-seq
```

Are the two definitions interchangeable? What is the difference between them?

Comment: for a LR parser, left recursive rules are easier to parse; rule resolution will be done exactly each time a new declaration appear, while in the right recursive rule, the whole declaration sequence must be parsed then will be resolved - which may cause overflow for the parser internal stack in case of very large sequence.
I guess they are interchangeable, the difference is that right recursive rules will add overhead for LR parser that may cause overflow and compilation failure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a vestige of C++'s C heritage.  The C grammar is (almost) [LALR(1)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LALR_parser), and therefore uses [left recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left_recursion) as much as possible.  The C++ grammar is not even vaguely LALR anymore, but many of the rules are still written in the form an LALR parser would prefer, because there's no reason to change them—any parser algorithm powerful enough to handle C++ doesn't care which type of syntactic recursion is used.